# PHP Cron Job: MySQL Query to Text File Weekly

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, automation

Alright, I finally figured out how to write my queries using MySQL. Does anyone know how to have a php file or even a jsp file (As the site is written in java) run a query, write it to a text file, and to have it run on a weekly basis  on the server?

Comment: if you have mysql >= 5.1 and relative privileges, you could even use events from mysql and schedule a task. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cron](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) to schedule a weekly job to run your PHP script.  Here is an example of a crontab entry that would run once a week (Sunday) at midnight:

`0 0 * * 0 /path/to/myscript.php`

You would be responsible for implementing the PHP code that runs the query, formats the output, and writes it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could run something like this in cron:

```
/path/to/mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME < /path/to/sql.sql > /tmp/outfile.txt;
```

sql.sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```